# Не до конца срабатывает bash-скрипт

Tags: ubuntu, bash, cron, ispmanager, isp

В общем, написал такой скрипт на bash для перезагрузки процесса в pm2:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
cd /root/.pm2/logs
cat /dev/null > $1-out-0.log
pm2 restart $1
cd
else
echo "!!! Требуется передать название нужного демона в pm2 !!!"
fi
```

Если запустить вручную через консоль - всё отлично срабатывает. Вешаю на cron в ISPManager, прописывая путь к скрипту и передавая требуемый параметр:

```
/home/restart.sh parser
```

При выполнении, удаляются только логи, но сам процесс pm2 не перезапускается. Права на скрипте стоят 750. В чём может быть проблема?

P.S. Передаваемое скрипту значение верно и написано без опечаток.

Comment: до pm2 полный путь пропиши — под cron'ом PATH может отличаться... и проверь пользователя, для которого в крон добавляешь...

Comment: Обычно, если включено, приходит сообщение на mail. Что там?

Comment: не только переменная PATH может отличаться. там отличаются гораздо больше параметров. я, в своё время, тоже с этим сталкивался. как уже сказали, смотрите в /var/spool/mail для вашего пользователя. кроме того, возьмите за правило использовать полные пути к файлам.